# Python pandas : column with ordered file names based on given sequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pattern-matching, string-matching

I would like to create a column in a data frame that contains a list of filenames based on certain sequence number.

I have the main data frame that looks like this:

```
  num letter 
0    0    I   
1    1    P  
2    2    I  
2    3    B  
2    4    P  
2    5    B  
2    6    I
```

and the filenames I have are: `I-0001.jpg, I-0002.jpg, I-0003.jpg, P-0001.jpg, P-0002.jpg, B-0001.jpg, B-0002.jpg`

The final result I would like is:

```
   num  letter  file
0    0    I   I-0001.jpg
1    1    P   P-0001.jpg
2    2    I   I-0002.jpg
2    3    B   B-0001.jpg
2    4    P   P-0002.jpg
2    5    B   B-0002.jpg
2    6    I   I-0003.jpg
```

So basically, the column file should be such, that any time I, or P, or B in "letter" column is found it picks that file name having I, P or B in the file name based on the numbering in each file.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join column `letter` with `Series` created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter per `letter`s, add `1`, convert to `string`s and if necessary add [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df['file'] = (df['letter'] + '-' +
              df.groupby('letter').cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(4) + '.jpg')
print (df)
   num letter        file
0    0      I  I-0001.jpg
1    1      P  P-0001.jpg
2    2      I  I-0002.jpg
2    3      B  B-0001.jpg
2    4      P  P-0002.jpg
2    5      B  B-0002.jpg
2    6      I  I-0003.jpg
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('letter').cumcount())
0    0
1    0
2    1
2    0
2    1
2    1
2    2
dtype: int64

print (df.groupby('letter').cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(4))
0    0001
1    0001
2    0002
2    0001
2    0002
2    0002
2    0003
dtype: object
```