# Add column with numbers based on count of value in other column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`colA` is what I currently have.

However, I'm trying to generate `colB`.

I want `colB` to contain the number `001` for each value. However if the associated `colA` value exists twice in that column, I want the `colB` number to then be `002`, and so on.

Hopefully the example below gives a better idea of what I'm looking for based on the `colA` values. I've been struggling to put together any real code for this.

EDIT: Struggling to explain this in words, so if you can think of a better way to explain it feel free to update my question.

```
colA   colB
BJ02   001
BJ02   002
CJ02   001
CJ03   001
CJ02   002
DJ01   001
DJ02   001
DJ07   001
DJ07   002
DJ07   003
```

Comment: you can get most of it with `df.groupby('colA').cumcount()+1`, do you need the exact same format with eading 0 as you described?

Comment: For string formatting, you can follow up with something like `colB.astype(str).str.zfill(3)`.

Comment: The canonical [groupby cumcount](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23435270/15497888). Links to similar cumcount +  zfill, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67631910/15497888, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48443698/15497888, https://stackoverflow.com/q/57986728/15497888

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby_cumcount`:

```
df['colB'] = df.groupby('colA').cumcount().add(1)
print(df)

# Output
   colA  colB
0  BJ02     1
1  BJ02     2
2  CJ02     1
3  CJ03     1
4  CJ02     2
5  DJ01     1
6  DJ02     1
7  DJ07     1
8  DJ07     2
9  DJ07     3
```

Suggested by @HenryEcker, use `zfill`:

```
df['colB'] = df.groupby('colA').cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)
print(df)

# Output:
   colA colB
0  BJ02  001
1  BJ02  002
2  CJ02  001
3  CJ03  001
4  CJ02  002
5  DJ01  001
6  DJ02  001
7  DJ07  001
8  DJ07  002
9  DJ07  003
```

Comment: [`.astype(str).str.zfill(3)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69622493/add-column-with-numbers-based-on-count-of-value-in-other-column-in-pandas#comment123061802_69622493) could be added to match output above. Like @hilberts_drinking_problem recommended

Answer (score 0):

You can use Counter() to count the frequency of each value in colA, then create a function to generate a list of values for colB.

```
from collections import Counter    
def count_value(colA):
     new_col = []
     colA = df[colA].tolist()
     freq_table = Counter(colA) # count the frequency of each value
     for value in colA:
          new_col.append('00' + str(freq_table[value]))
     return new_col
df['colB'] = count_value(df['colA'])
```